# Chef: How do I override default attributes in roles?

Tags: chef-infra

I'm using the opscode [nginx cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/nginx) for configuring the nginx server on my nodes.
The nginx cookbook has some default attributes I'd like to override in my role ("web_server").

These are the attributes I'd like to override:

```
default['nginx']['version'] = "1.2.2" # in cookbooks/nginx/attributes/default.rb
default['nginx']['source']['prefix'] = "/opt/nginx-#{node['nginx']['version']}" # in cookbooks/nginx/attributes/source.rb
```

In my roles/web_server.rb file I have something like this:

```
name "web_server"
description "Setup a web server"
run_list "role[base]", "recipe[nginx]"
override_attributes 'nginx' => {
  'install_method' => "source",
  'version' => "1.2.3",
  'source' => { "prefix" => "/opt/nginx", "checksum" => nil }
}
```

However, when running the chef-client the nginx recipe ignores my overrides and uses the default ones.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Haven't you forgot to upload role to chef-server (if you are using it) ?

Comment: Are you running chef-client with or without a custom run list (-o)? Today I learned (after 2-3 hours debugging) that attributes set in the role/node is not used when overriding the run list.

Comment: I encountered the same issue :/ I am pretty sure I set override_attributes in role, and I only use default in my attributes file. I bet this is kind of chef bug or what.

Comment: Did you solved this problem?

Comment: @AndréRoaldseth thanks for your comment. I spent hours trying to figure out why my role attributes weren't getting picked up when running my recipe via -o. Did you find documentation for this behavior anywhere?

Comment: Putting attributes in roles is evil!! I would *strongly* advise against it! 
There's so many other places for them (too many), do yourself a favour, and just use roles primarily for the run_lists.  ; )

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Chef Attribute Preference](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence) document, this should work:

```
name "web_server"
description "Setup a web server"
run_list "role[base]", "recipe[nginx]"
default_attributes 'nginx' => {
  'install_method' => "source",
  'version' => "1.2.3",
  'source' => { "prefix" => "/opt/nginx", "checksum" => nil }
}
```

*You shouldn’t use `override_attributes` in roles*. Once you start using overrides instead of defaults, you’ll quickly end up finding you’ve used the strongest possible override and have no further way to override it. Use `default_overrides` instead.

The precedence rules around attributes, using only the `default` level are actually pretty same:

1. If there is one, the attribute from the role is used, e.g., `require_two_factor_auth` is forced to true with `default_overrides` in `role[single_sign_on]`, even in QA
2. If there is one, the attribute from the environment is used, e.g., `require_two_factor_auth` is forced to true in `production`
3. If there is one, the attribute from the recipe is used, e.g., `require_two_factor_auth` is set to true in `auth::two_factor`
4. Finally, the sane default attribute from the default attribute file is used, e.g., `require_two_factor_auth = false`

However, it’s extremely unusual for the same attribute to be set in all four of those places, though. If the correct value of the attribute really depends on the recipe and the role and and the environment, then usually the resulting value combines features of all three, and a different attribute is set at each level and combined in the recipe.

---

If this isn’t working, two possibilities are:

- Edited role not uploaded to server
- Overriding run list with `chef-client -o "recipe[nginx]"` instead of `chef-client -o role[web_server]` or plain `chef-client`

If that’s not the case, please provide more detail. I use this all the time and it’s always worked, and I’d be concerned if there were edge cases where this does not behave as documented.

Answer (score 4):

The attribute precedence chart [1] shows that these four options rank above your role:

```
12. An override attribute located in an environment
13. A force_override attribute located in a cookbook attribute file
14. A force_override attribute located in a recipe
15. An automatic attribute identified by Ohai at the start of the chef-client run
```

If these don't appear to be the cause, then perhaps changing your formatting might help. I would write it like:

```
override_attributes(
  nginx: {
    install_method: 'source',
    version: '1.2.3',
    source: {
      prefix: '/opt/nginx',
      checksum: [ ],
    },
  }
)
```

[1] https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence

Answer (score 2):

This question is from 2012 and is very, very old.  The first suggestion I have is to be more explicit around creating the hash argument, and the precedence level should be set to default, never override:

```
name "web_server"
description "Setup a web server"
run_list "role[base]", "recipe[nginx]"
default_attributes({
  'nginx' => {
    'install_method' => "source",
    'version' => "1.2.3",
    'source' => { "prefix" => "/opt/nginx", "checksum" => nil }
  }
})
```

The problem is likely related to [Derived Attributes](https://coderanger.net/derived-attributes/) that were being used in the nginx cookbook:

```
default['nginx']['version'] = "1.2.2" # in cookbooks/nginx/attributes/default.rb
default['nginx']['source']['prefix'] = "/opt/nginx-#{node['nginx']['version']}" # in cookbooks/nginx/attributes/source.rb
```

If a higher-level override is not set by previously parsed configuration at the time that the second line is parsed it will immediately pick up the first line.  Since at least Chef 11 role attributes always win over default attributes in attributes files.  Even back in Chef 10 override role attributes should have been already parsed and should beat the default set in the first line here.  I do not know why the override attribute was not working for this user back in 2012.  This may have been related to simple bugginess in Chef 11.x versions around generating the merged view of all the precedence levels (bugs long since fixed, but I cannot recall the details any more).

I would encourage anyone currently reading this question to use PolicyFiles, which replaces roles, environments and Berkshelf files.  All of the latter are still supported but no further development is going into them.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the attribute precedence order here? https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence

Make sure there are no attributes overridden on a node directly in your recipe.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I could guess is that these attributes must have been over-ridden by 
force_overridden attribute.
Also ensure that the attributes you have over-ridden are available for the runlist(since I'm skeptical about the way you have arranged your role file)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use override attributes in role editor (in web or knife role edit)

```
{
  "name": "web_server",
  "description": "nginx version",
  "json_class": "Chef::Role",
  "default_attributes": {

  },
  "override_attributes": {
    "nginx": {
      "version": "1.2.2"
    }
  },
  "chef_type": "role",
  "run_list": [
  "recipe[]",
  "recipe[]"
  ],
  "env_run_lists": {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with parentheses? I tried your example with parentheses and got the default attributes overridden.

```
# your roles/web_server.rb file

override_attributes(
  'nginx' => {
    'install_method' => "source",
    'version' => "1.2.3",
    'source' => { "prefix" => "/opt/nginx", "checksum" => nil }
  }
)
```