# Use Chef roles to insert attributes

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, role, zabbix

I was reading the [Roles](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_roles.html) page at Opscode, and from what I understand, my role file, a ruby DSL, should look like this:

```
name "role_zabbix_agent_corp"
description "Assigning Server IP's to the config for Corporate side."
run_list "recipe[zabbix_agent_corp]"
default_attributes "zabbix_agent_corp" => { 
    "Server" => [ "zabbix-server1.com" ],
    "ServerActive" => [ "zabbix-server1.com" ]
}
```

However, when I perform the `chef-client` run, the attributes specified above do not fill in the blank spots in the config file. The name of the cookbook is `zabbix_agent_corp` and the attributes file is the default.rb file. Below are the attributes that are supposed to be filled in:

```
default['zabbix']['agent']['conf']['Server'] = ""
default['zabbix']['agent']['conf']['ServerActive'] = ""
```

Is there something I need to do differently to call the attributes in the cookbook, or is my role file not written correctly?

Comment: zabbix_agent_corp vs ['zabbix']['agent']['conf']. Feel the difference in the last part of path.

Comment: So, instead of what I have right after default_attributes, put in the hash? `default_attributes "default['zabbix']['agent']['conf']" =>`?

Comment: There might be a duplicate, or similar post from another person at [Chef: How do I override default attributes in roles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144592/chef-how-do-i-override-default-attributes-in-roles)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hash you create in the role needs to match the definition of the attribute.

In this instance your role should look like:

```
default_attributes
  'zabbix' => {
    'agent' => {
      'conf' => {
        'Server' => 'zabbix-server1.com',
        'ServerActive' => 'zabbix-server1.com'
      }
    }
  }
```

See the [Ruby DSL](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_roles.html#ruby-dsl) section of the Chef docs for a complete reference.

**Note**: the Chef convention is that attribute names should be all lower-case with underscores instead of Pascal/CamelCase. E.g. `ServerActive` should be `server_active`.

Comment: The Zabbix naming for those variables is just like that. Otherwise I'd follow those guidelines.