# chef override_attributes doesn't work

Tags: automation, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have following attribute in chef-repo/site-cookbooks/datadog/attributes/default.rb

```
default['datadog']['yumrepo'] = "http://yum.datadoghq.com/rpm"
```

I want to override this attributes for one node, so I added following in node file on chef server

```
"override_attributes": {
  "datadog": {
    "yumrepo": "http://yum.datadoghq.com/rpm/x86_64/"
  }
},
```

then ran chef-clent, but looks like override_attributes is not in effect for that node.

any idea whats wrong here ?

Comment: check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144592/chef-how-do-i-override-default-attributes-in-roles but if you are able to make your own recipe try to make new  yum repository as a variable

Comment: initially I followed that link & created my override, but still dont know why its not working.

Comment: Can you give more information? What version of chef? are there any other recipes/roles/environment files that use datadog that are overriding that attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the attribute by adding the attribute attribute in any of the resources as follows:

```
<some resource> do
    attribute %w[datadog yumrepo], "http://yum.datadoghq.com/rpm/x86_64/"
    action :<some action>
end
```

If the node has an attribute, this will override it with the value you provide.